# Running two independent threads in parallel

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I have written a server program with two threads:

```
1. For sending data to client side.
2. For receiving data from client side
```

Now when execute them, the server accepts the request and thread to send data is created and it starts sending data to client but since it is joinable, it will execute until it completes its execution and the other thread does not get created and the control remains in this thread.

What I need to apply in order to make both the threads run simultaneously?

Comment: "since it is joinable, it does not leave the cpu and the other thread does not get created" This doesn't make sense. Please show at least some pseudocode. Also sending and receiving using the same socket from different threads is not a good idea.

Comment: Are you running this on a multi-processor/multi-core machine?

Comment: no ,On a single processor

Comment: @user3032010, then, AFAIK, your threads will be [time-sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice).

Comment: yes ,I too think so ,but as have debugged it, the second thread does get created .

Comment: @user3032010, Do you mean to say that the receive thread does not run at all? Also, whenever you reply to a comment, please tag the commenter by typing an '@' and then the user name.

Comment: @user3032010 Creating a joinable thread is non-blocking call. So, your main code shall continue running (more ...  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html). So, this is not your root cause of your problem. Please provide a pseudo code so we can help you.

Comment: @Bechir, I have a feeling the OP has misunderstood some fundamental concept :)

Comment: @user3032010, How did you debug this? Which debugger did you use?

Comment: @doomster 'sending and receiving using the same socket from different threads is not a good idea' - why?  It's common practice.  It works OK.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is no synchronization ("in parallel") going on. If you have a mutex protecting access to the socket, you are not using it from different threads at the same time. Alternatively, if your protocol handling somehow coordinates this without explicitly locking, you also avoid concurrent accesses. Concerning real parallel reads and writes, I don't know of any guarantee (which would be system-specific and a question of QOI) that this is supported, so I'd assume it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for pthread. Here is a sample code I wrote when I learned how threads  work. Its a counter. The first thread adds one to a variable each secound, and the other prints it out.

```
#include<pthread.h>     //for simultanius threads
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>      //for the _sleep function

//global variables, both thread can reach thease.
int a = 0;
int run = 1;

void *fv(void)
{
   while( run )
    {
         _sleep(1000);
         a++;
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create( &thread, 0, fv, 0 );
    printf( "%d", a );
    while( a < 60 )
    {
        int last = a;
        while( last == a )
           _sleep(50); //let's not burn the cpu.
        printf( "\r%d", a );
        _sleep(500); //a won't change for a while
    }
    run = 0;
    pthread_join( thread, NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MartinJames You see the question was how to run the two threads simultaniously. At least I think it was, the question did't make too much sense to me at some parts, but I'm sure the asker had no idea how to do this. I think this is a simple and good example.

Answer (score 0):

I had not misunderstood the concept but the problem was that I was performing following steps:

```
    1. creating sending thread.
    2. Making it joinable.
    3. creating receiving thread.
    4. Making it joinable.
```

Now what was happening ,Once the sending threading thread was joinable ,receiving thread was not being created.
Now the problem is resolved The correct sequence is:

```
    1. creating sending thread.
    2. creating receiving thread.
    3. Making  sending thread joinable
    4. Making  receiving thread joinable.
```

Now both the threads are created first and then executes parallely.